# How do I calculate A using B to subtract A from B to get C?

Tags: php, database, date, calculation

I have three records in the table.

1. First is called A and determines the beginning of the stay. Is
   written in date format. (2020-04-14)
2. Second is called B and determines the end of the stay. Is written in
   date format. (2020-04-16)
3. Third is called C and should store the calculated number of days during the stay as nbr :

   ```
   nbr * 50. (A - B = C and C *50 = C )

   $A = trim($_POST['A']);

   $B = trim($_POST['B']);

   $C = ??
   ```

How do I calculate A using B to subtract A from B to get C?
How do I multiply the result of C by * 50 and save it again in variable C which will be stored in the database?

Example:

A = 2020-04-14

B = 2020-04-16

C = 2020-04-14 - 2020-04-16 = 2
 and 2 * 50 = 100; 
C = 100 and save to the database.

Can you help me please? :)

Comment: Which bit of this are you having trouble with? Receiving the input? Getting the number of days between two dates? Saving to the database? All of it?

Comment: *"Can you help me please?"* - Help you how exactly? You seem to be doing well so far; what isn't working the way you'd like it it? What is the data source? DB schema/value RDBMS? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
$start_date = strtotime($A);
$end_date = strtotime($B);
$diff = $start_date - $end_date;
$C =  round($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```